# Testing association validations with RSpec and FactoryGirl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, rspec, factory-bot

I'm currently trying to write an RSpec test for a validation method. This method is triggered when the record is updated, saved or created. Here is what I have so far:

**product.rb (model)**

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base

validate :single_product 

  # Detects if a product has more than one SKU when attempting to set the single product field as true
  # The sku association needs to map an attribute block in order to count the number of records successfully
  # The standard self.skus.count is performed using the record ID, which none of the SKUs currently have
  #
  # @return [boolean]
  def single_product
    if self.single && self.skus.map { |s| s.active }.count > 1
      errors.add(:single, " product cannot be set if the product has more than one SKU.")
      return false
    end
  end
end
```

**products.rb (FactoryGirl test data)**

```
FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :product do
        sequence(:name)  { |n| "#{Faker::Lorem.word}#{Faker::Lorem.characters(8)}#{n}" }
        meta_description { Faker::Lorem.characters(10) }
        short_description { Faker::Lorem.characters(15) } 
        description { Faker::Lorem.characters(20) }
        sku { Faker::Lorem.characters(5) }
        sequence(:part_number) { |n| "GA#{n}" }
        featured false
        active false
        sequence(:weighting) { |n| n }
        single false

        association :category

        factory :product_skus do 
            after(:build) do |product, evaluator|
                build_list(:sku, 3, product: product)
            end
        end
    end
end
```

**product_spec.rb (unit test)**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Product do
    describe "Setting a product as a single product" do
        let!(:product) { build(:product_skus, single: true) }

        context "when the product has more than one SKU" do

            it "should raise an error" do
                expect(product).to have(1).errors_on(:single)
            end
        end
    end
end
```

As you can see from the **singe_product** method, I'm trying to trigger an error on the *single* attribute when the single attribute is set to true and the product has more than one associated SKU. However, when running the test the product has no associated SKUs and therefore fails the unit test shown above.

How do I build a record and generate associated SKUs which can be counted (e.g: product.skus.count) and validated before they are all created in FactoryGirl?

Answer (score 0):

You could write this like

```
  it 'should raise an error' do
    product = build(:product_skus, single: true)

    expect(product).not_to be_valid
  end
```

Comment: to downvoter: you can either use not_to or to_not. One is an alias of the other! So, no, this is not an incorrect syntax!